# How to correctly catch and display an error in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, error-handling

I'm throwing an error from my backend if a data entry already exists like so:

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();

  if (!currentUser) {
    throw new Error("Must be logged in to add reminders!");
  }

  console.log(currentUser);

  const body = await request.json();

  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      email: currentUser.email as string,
    },
  });

  const exists = await prisma.reminder.findUnique({
    where: {
      title: body.title,
    },
  });

  if (exists) {
    throw new Error("Reminder exists, consider changing title!");
  }

  const reminder = await prisma.reminder.create({
    data: {
      userId: user?.id,
      ...body,
    },
  });

  return NextResponse.json(reminder);
}
```

And all I want to do is display that exact error on the frontend:

```
async function onSubmit(data: ReminderFormSchemaType) {
    axios
      .post<ReminderFormSchemaType>("/api/reminders", { ...data })
      .then((response) => {
        toast.success("Reminder added!");
        router.refresh();
      })
      .catch((err: Error) => {
        toast.error(err.message);
      });
    console.log(data);
  }
```

This code catches the error correctly but instead of displaying the error I threw myself, I get a 'Request failed with status 500' in my toast display.

How do I correctly type the error so I receive exactly what I threw from my backend?

Comment: Are you using any framework for the backend? You need to return a response like `{code: 409, body: err.message}`. Show some more backend code to get a better the context.

Comment: I updated the code, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

To get errors correctly in the frontend, you don't actually throw errors in the backend, but rather return responses with a 4xx HTTP code. The backend would be like:

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();

  if (!currentUser) {
    return NextResponse.json({error: "Must be logged in to add reminders!"}, {status: 401});
  }

  console.log(currentUser);

  const body = await request.json();

  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      email: currentUser.email as string,
    },
  });

  const exists = await prisma.reminder.findUnique({
    where: {
      title: body.title,
    },
  });

  if (exists) {
    return NextResponse.json({error: "Reminder exists, consider changing title!"}, {status: 409});
  }

  const reminder = await prisma.reminder.create({
    data: {
      userId: user?.id,
      ...body,
    },
  });

  return NextResponse.json(reminder);
}
```

And then get the errors in the frontend:

```
async function onSubmit(data: ReminderFormSchemaType) {
    axios
      .post<ReminderFormSchemaType>("/api/reminders", { ...data })
      .then((response) => {
        toast.success("Reminder added!");
        router.refresh();
      })
      .catch((err: Error) => {
        toast.error(err.response.data.error);
      });
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: response doesn't exist on the error object